# Show webpage with watermark in Chromium

Tags: html, chromium

I am implementing a secure browser based on Chromium which is used to browse sensitive web pages. I want to add watermarks to all web pages in my browser (without changing webpages at backend of course). Instead of writing chrome extension, I want to add this feature in Chromium source codes directly. However I am not familiar with Chromium codes, where can I start with?

Comment: Not Possible. You need to write a chorme extension. If chrome lets people edit the source code then anyone will do anything, right? If someone deletes the whole source code of stackoverflow, then what would happen? That's why the browsers don't allow it.

Comment: i mean i build my browser based on chromium, this browser shows all web pages with watermark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding watermarks is something you want to do only for yourself via the browser, so only on YOUR browser you see these watermarks, you can use something like Tampermonkey (to add/edit/modify only in runtime) the webpages.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en

there are plenty of examples on how to add content to a webpage via this extension.

Comment: the reason i dont want to use extension is that it can be disabled by users, either disable from extension settings or removed from extensions folder in file system.

Comment: so if the scenario is NOT only for your browser, then you cannot do this.. you cannot put watermarks on code you have no access to from its backend.

Comment: of course it is for my browser only, i dont want to change web pages at backend. my browser downloads webpage files like html, insert watermark to html and display it, it should be possbile

Comment: you should've clarified all of these details in your initial question... it is not too late to add them there even now.. If you are downloading the htmls, you can post-process the downloaded html files by adding a div at the end, and CSS, which can easily add an absolute positioned watermark to each html..

Comment: yes, my question is in order to implement this what part of Chromium codes should i check.

Comment: you should not touch the Chromium code.. did you read what I wrote? Do you actually do any research of your own?

Comment: Like Ron mentioned, you can do so by using extensions, also looks like you are using your Chromium fork. I have answered one question regarding bundling extensions into Chromium forks. That might be helpful to you

Comment: as i mentioned extension is not what i want because user can disable it or remove its files. If there is any approach that prevents user to disable the extention in ANY way, it might be a solution to me.

Comment: If you will be doing this on your own, with your output files, which you process, what USER then? Please try to explain your whole use case, not just few fragments of it, so that we get the whole picture of what you need to accomplish, example goal where, what, how you see the end result.... THEN you might get a more specific answer...

Comment: it is a secure browser used to browse sensitive data, watermark is for DLP(Data Loss Protection)

Comment: if you plan to do so w/o using any extension then it will be a very big and complex task. The architecture of Chromium will make it very difficult to do so. You should spend some time learning it's architecture and code base, then you will know why